# Are coupon codes okay to post?

Tags: discussion, disclosure

[I'm assuming no, but don't think I've seen it explicitly addressed, in which case this can become documentation.]

New user [@yasyf](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/19691/yasyf) is repeatedly posting links to a certain payment provider. (6 so far.) I've [already inquired](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/36486/4502) re: disclosure, but the posts also include a discount code. While the *links* to the site are non-affiliate, there's no real way to verify that the discount code doesn't have the same ultimate effect, and they probably don't belong here regardless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the difference between disclosure such as "I work for this company, but we do provide a product which meets the needs you list in your question" and "use this link/code, I get money out of it" is that in the latter case the answerers credibility goes way down, even with disclosure.

That's assuming they do disclose, which they may not.

So I'd say no.

Comment: I have no issue with stopping this (I apologize), but I don't agree with this. I left full disclosure, and the code was related to my answer. I am suggesting that the questioner try both services to see which he likes, and this is impossible to do for free without the promo code. Not to mention, it was only on two of about eight other posts thus far.

Comment: We're trying to come up with an answer that covers all cases, rather than trying to decide each case on it's own. As it happens I think what you did was OK, but I'm trying to think what we do in general.

Comment: Ok that makes sense; I was merely confused as it appears that, as a result of this, someone has gone and deleted the relevant parts of those posts.

Answer (score 5):

The [FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion) is pretty clear on this point:

> Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product
>   or website, so be it.
>
> ...
>
> If a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product
>   or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons.

Limited-time promotional codes may answer shopping questions, but [shopping questions don't really belong here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).